# HVAC HEIL blowing 5 amp fuse

Tags: hvac, troubleshooting

My defrost control board on HEIL (international Comfort Products) keeps blowing the 5 amp control voltage fuse. Im a Tech but I need some advise as I dont usually work on HVAC. I checked the TSTAT wires to see if they had a short and nope they didnt. I went ahead and disconnected them from the board and also disconnected the contact, reverse switch and fan. I turned it back on and it blew another fuse. I looked at the board and it has a small area that looks like it got warm but not bad. I took pics if that would help! Any advice?

Comment: Can you post the photos, as well as the model # and wiring diagram of your furnace?